Is it correct to put the Navbar inside the main layout?
I've had problems with the navbar in React Next.js because I don't want it to show in the grouped auth views. However, even though (auth) has its own layout, the navbar still shows.
Here’s how the routes would go:

app

layout.tsx (main layout)
(auth)

layout.tsx (specific layout without navbar)
login
register





Here is the code for my main layout.
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import Navbar from '@/components/navbar'
import "@/styles/globals.css";


export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "SportHub",
  description: "Gestiona tus eventos deportivos en línea con SportHub",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className=''
      >
       
        <Navbar />
        
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

And here is the code for my (auth) layout as well.
export default function LayoutAuth({
    children,
}: {
    children:React.ReactNode;
}){
    return (
    <div>
        <main>{children}</main>
    </div>
    
);
}

I've tried putting the navbar in the main page, and it works there, but that's not the solution I'm looking for since it would mean I have to put it in all other views, exporting it one by one.

You can make your navbar client component and then show it based on conditions.
Use usePathname hook from next/navigation.
`
const pathname = usePathname();
const isAuthPages = pathname === "/login" || pathname === 
"register"

// wrap the whole component in the fragment like 

return (

<>

{!isAuthPages  && 
//your navbar 
}
</>
)S

`
Second option you can create another group layout and add all the pages where you want to show this navbar.
